# Why isn't my div being applied inline?

Tags: html, css

I've tried making my div's on the same line. I've tried `floating`, changing the `display` property and messing with the `width` and `height` properties. But nothing is working:

```css
/* font */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
/* end of font */

/* clear settings */
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
}
/* end of clear settings */

/* nav */
  #nav {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #009ACD;
  }
/* end of nav */

/* info nav */
  #primary_nav_wrap
{
 width: 1600px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #1F1F1F;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 left: 3%;
 top: 5px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:15px;
 padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 color: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a:hover {
  background: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover a {
  color: black;
  background: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li a:hover {
  background: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #F4F4F4;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0;
 margin-top: 0.2px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-top: none;
 z-index: 50;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px;
 position: relative;
 left: 0px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:7.5px 9px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block
}
/* end of info nav */

/* course div */
  #course_div {
    width: 1200px;
    position: relative;
    left: 180px;
    top: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  #course_img {
    width: 216px;
    height: 121.5px;
  }
  
  #course_info {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 204px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  
   #course_div a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    width: 204px;
  }
  
  #course_main {
    width: 216px;
    
  }
  
/* end of course div */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Hacked Genius </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <!-- nav -->
      <div id='nav'>
        
      </div>
    <!-- end of nav -->
    
    <!-- info nav -->
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Development</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mobile Apps</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Programming Languages</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Game Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Databases</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Software Testing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Software Engineering</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Development Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">E-Commerce</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Business</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Entrepreneurship</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Communications</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Strategy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Operations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Project Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Business Law</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Data and Anylytics</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home Business</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Human Resources</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Industry</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Real Estate</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">IT & Software</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">IT Certification</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Network & Security</a>
      <li><a href="#">Hardware</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Operating Systems</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>
<li><a href="#">Office Productivity</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Microsoft</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Apple</a>
      <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SAP</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Intuit</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Salesforce</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Oracle</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>
<li><a href="#">Personal Development</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Personal Transformation</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Productivity</a>
      <li><a href="#">Leadership</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Personal Finance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Career Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Parenting & Relationships</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Happiness</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Religion & Spirituality</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Personal Brand Building</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Creativity</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Influence</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Self Esteem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stress Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Memory and Study Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Motivation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Design</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Graphic Design</a>
      <li><a href="#">Design Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Game Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Design Thinking</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3D & Animation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fashion</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Architectural Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Interior Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Marketing</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Digital Marketing</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Search Engine Optimization</a>
      <li><a href="#">Social Media Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Marketing Fundamentals</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Analystics & Automation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Public Relations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Video & Mobile Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Content Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Non-Digital Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Growth Hacking</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Affiliate Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Product Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Lifestyle</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Life Hacks</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Arts & Crafts</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Food & Beverage</a>
      <li><a href="#">Beauty & Makeup</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gaming</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home Improvement</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pet Care & Training</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Photography</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Digital Photography</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Photography Fundamentals</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Portraits</a>
      <li><a href="#">Landscape</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Black & White</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Photography Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mobile Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Travel Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Commercial Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Wedding Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Video Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Health & Fitness</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Fitness</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">General Health</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sports</a>
      <li><a href="#">Nutrition</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Yoga</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mental Health</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dieting</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Self Defense</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Safety & First Aid</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Meditation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Language</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">English</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">German</a>
      <li><a href="#">French</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Japanese</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portuguese</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Chinese</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Russian</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Latin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Arabic</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hebrew</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Italian</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Music</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Instruments</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Production</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Music Fundamentals</a>
      <li><a href="#">Vocal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Music Techniques</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Music Software</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Academics</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Social Science</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Math & Science</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Humanities</a>
</ul>


</ul>
</ul>
</ul>
</ul>
</ul>
</ul>

</ul>

</ul>
</nav>
    <!-- end of info nav -->
    
    <div id='course_div'>
      
   <a href='#'> <div id='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>
        
         <div id='course_info'>
          Ki
        </div> </a>
        
         <a href='#'> <div id='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>
        
         <div id='course_info'>
          Two
        </div> </a>
        
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can try display: flex. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your code.  The div tags are all messed up.

I fixed it here -> https://jsfiddle.net/kn7g54j1/1/

Is this what you want?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Hacked Genius </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- nav -->
      <div id='nav'>

      </div>
    <!-- end of nav -->

    <!-- info nav -->
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Development</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mobile Apps</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Programming Languages</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Game Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Databases</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Software Testing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Software Engineering</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Development Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">E-Commerce</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Business</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Entrepreneurship</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Communications</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Strategy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Operations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Project Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Business Law</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Data and Anylytics</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home Business</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Human Resources</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Industry</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Real Estate</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">IT & Software</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">IT Certification</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Network & Security</a>
      <li><a href="#">Hardware</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Operating Systems</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>
<li><a href="#">Office Productivity</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Microsoft</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Apple</a>
      <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SAP</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Intuit</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Salesforce</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Oracle</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>
<li><a href="#">Personal Development</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Personal Transformation</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Productivity</a>
      <li><a href="#">Leadership</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Personal Finance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Career Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Parenting & Relationships</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Happiness</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Religion & Spirituality</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Personal Brand Building</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Creativity</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Influence</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Self Esteem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stress Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Memory and Study Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Motivation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Design</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Graphic Design</a>
      <li><a href="#">Design Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Game Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Design Thinking</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3D & Animation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fashion</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Architectural Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Interior Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Marketing</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Digital Marketing</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Search Engine Optimization</a>
      <li><a href="#">Social Media Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Marketing Fundamentals</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Analystics & Automation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Public Relations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Video & Mobile Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Content Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Non-Digital Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Growth Hacking</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Affiliate Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Product Marketing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Lifestyle</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Life Hacks</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Arts & Crafts</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Food & Beverage</a>
      <li><a href="#">Beauty & Makeup</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gaming</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home Improvement</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pet Care & Training</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Photography</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Digital Photography</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Photography Fundamentals</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Portraits</a>
      <li><a href="#">Landscape</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Black & White</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Photography Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mobile Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Travel Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Commercial Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Wedding Photography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Video Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Health & Fitness</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Fitness</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">General Health</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sports</a>
      <li><a href="#">Nutrition</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Yoga</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mental Health</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dieting</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Self Defense</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Safety & First Aid</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Meditation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Language</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">English</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">German</a>
      <li><a href="#">French</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Japanese</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portuguese</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Chinese</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Russian</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Latin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Arabic</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hebrew</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Italian</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Music</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Instruments</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Production</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Music Fundamentals</a>
      <li><a href="#">Vocal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Music Techniques</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Music Software</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a href="#">Academics</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Social Science</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Math & Science</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Humanities</a>
</ul>


</ul>
</nav>
    <!-- end of info nav -->

    <div id='course_div'>

   <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Ki
          </div> </div></a>

         <a href='#'> <div class='course_main'>
        <img src='https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/236832_f09d_19.jpg' id='course_img'>

         <div id='course_info'>
          Two
          </div> </div></a>


    </div>

  </body>
</html>



/* font */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
/* end of font */

/* clear settings */
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
}
/* end of clear settings */

/* nav */
  #nav {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #009ACD;
  }
/* end of nav */

/* info nav */
  #primary_nav_wrap
{
    width: 1600px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #1F1F1F;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    left: 3%;
    top: 5px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:15px;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a:hover {
  background: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover a {
  color: black;
  background: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li a:hover {
  background: white;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #F4F4F4;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0;
    margin-top: 0.2px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
    z-index: 50;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:200px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:7.5px 9px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
    top:0;
    left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}
/* end of info nav */

/* course div */
  #course_div {
    width: 1200px;
    position: relative;
    left: 180px;
    top: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  #course_img {
    width: 216px;
    height: 121.5px;
  }

  #course_info {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 204px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

   .course_div a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    width: 204px;
  }

  .course_main {
    width: 216px;
    display: inline-block;

  }

/* end of course div */
```